# Difference between time signatures

Tags: notation, sheet-music

What is the difference between 4/4 and 8/8 time? 4/4 means 4 crotchets in a bar and 8/8 means 8 quavers in a bar, but 4 crotchets mean 8 quavers.

Is it just a question of notation? If so, why isn't all music X/2, since we can divide the semibreve up to sixteen times (up to the semiquaver)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/568/is-there-any-real-world-difference-between-time-signatures-such-as-4-4-and-8-8/571

Answer (score 8):

8/8 is sometimes used for music where the 8th-note groupings are consistently not 2+2+2+2 - i.e. NOT a traditional 'four in the bar'.

There's also 2/2, for when the half-note is the main beat. In marches and show tunes notating this as 'Cut Time' is more usual.

Even, very occasionally, 1/1.[image]